# Relationship using dates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationships

I am trying to pull data based on each day of the month and create a chart plotting different sets of data. I was thinking that if I had a "dates" table, I could create some relationships based off of the date and the related tables created_at timestamp. Example, Date = 2016-05-01 and relates to users by created_at so I could show how many new sign ups on that day.

If I use a date format for the "Dates" table, and then try to relate a created_at timesstamp,

I get the following error:
**ErrorException in HasOneOrMany.php line 202:
Illegal offset type**

So I think I need to make sure that the date and the related timestamp are formatted the same prior to the query or there will not be a match. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your Date model you will have to convert the date field to the Carbon instance:

```
protected $dates = ['field_name'];
```

Comment: No, the issue is that the Dates table shows the date like this: 2016-05-01 but the users created_at field is returning looking like this: select * from `users` where `users`.`created_at` in ('2015-11-01', '2015-11-02', '2015-11-03', '2015-11-04', '2015-11-05', '2015-11-06', '2015-11-07', '2015-11-08', '2015-11-09', '2015-11-10', '2015-11-11', '2015-11-12', '2015-11-13') and `users`.`deleted_at` is null - which means the record is not a match because it has the timestamp data. Not sure how to solve that.

Comment: You can always set timestamps to false, but to be honest, I'm not really sure what are you trying to do? :)